# Angularjs and Bootstrap Pagination. Change active number background color

Tags: css, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to change the background color of an active page number. Anyone who knows how to customize template?

```
<pagination 
             ng-model="currentPage"
              total-items="items"
              max-size="maxSize"  
              previous-text="Предыдущая страница"
               next-text="Следующая страница">
</pagination>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `pagination` is no longer a valid directive name, use `uib-pagination`
2. As you can see by this markup taken from the [template file](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/pagination/pagination.html)

   ```
   <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index" ng-class="{active: page.active,disabled: ngDisabled&&!page.active}" class="pagination-page"><a href ng-click="selectPage(page.number, $event)" ng-disabled="ngDisabled&&!page.active" uib-tabindex-toggle>{{page.text}}</a></li>
   ```

The `.active` class is already applied to the current selected page, so you only need to use css to override it.

Comment: Yeah, why did not I think about this solution :) Thanks! ^^

Comment: ui-bootstrap is not the least intuitive when it comes to modifying it's appearance, you have to take a look at the markup/styles/source code